# Two lines are interpreted as one while reading from file

Tags: python, file-io

I try to read a bunch of file line by line, and extract the headers from them.

```
for i in range(2, 43):
    file = open('/instances/instance' + repr(i) + '.txt')
    lines = file.readlines()
    header = [int(x) for x in lines[0].split()]
    print(repr(i) + ':', header)
```

while some of the headers extracted fine, some of them are concatenated with the line below. The output is:

```
2: [1, 3, 50, 5]
3: [1, 1, 50, 5]
4: [1, 5, 75, 2]
5: [1, 6, 75, 5]
6: [1, 1, 75, 10]
7: [1, 4, 100, 2]
8: [1, 5, 100, 5]
9: [1, 1, 100, 8]
10: [1, 4, 100, 5]
11: [1, 4, 139, 5]
12: [1, 3, 163, 5]
13: [1, 9, 417, 7]
14: [1, 2, 20, 4]
15: [1, 2, 38, 40, 30]
16: [1, 2, 56, 40, 40]
17: [1, 4, 40, 40, 20]
18: [1, 4, 76, 40, 30]
19: [1, 4, 112, 40, 40]
20: [1, 4, 184, 40, 60]
21: [1, 6, 60, 40, 20]
22: [1, 6, 114, 4]
23: [1, 6, 168, 40, 40]
24: [1, 3, 51, 60, 20]
25: [1, 3, 51, 60, 20]
26: [1, 3, 51, 60, 20]
27: [1, 6, 102, 60, 20]
28: [1, 6, 102, 60, 20]
29: [1, 6, 102, 60, 20]
30: [1, 9, 153, 60, 20]
31: [1, 9, 153, 60, 20]
32: [1, 9, 153, 60, 20]
33: [1, 2, 48, 4500, 200]
34: [1, 4, 96, 4480, 195]
35: [1, 6, 144, 4460, 190]
36: [1, 8, 192, 4440, 185]
37: [1, 10, 240, 4420, 180]
38: [1, 12, 288, 4400, 175]
39: [1, 3, 72, 6500, 200]
40: [1, 6, 144, 6475, 190]
41: [1, 9, 216, 6450, 180]
42: [1, 12, 288, 6425, 170]
```

Until `instance33.txt`, the header is extracted perfectly fine. However, when reading `instance33.txt`;

```
1 2 48 4
500 200
500 200
500 200
500 200
```

the first two lines are interpreted as one:

```
33: [1, 2, 48, 4500, 200]
```

Although the other files are formatted just the same, this strange behavior happens after `instance33.txt`.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: You might have some other line break which Python isn't interpreting correctly. If you know the number of lines in `instance33.txt`, I would try to `assert len(lines) == file_lengths[i]` where `file_lengths[33]` is the number of lines you know.

Comment: Windows, Linux and OS X use different code for new line  '\n', '\n\r', '\r'. Editors can use different code too. But `open` should recognize all types. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: To add to @furas comment I will say that you are possibly on window and the file 33 somehow is corrupted with a bad 'new line' '\n' only or '\r' only for that line.

Comment: I suggest you open that file with an editor and force the break for that line and try again.

Comment: @furas I think you are right. When editing with Notepad++, I see that there are different line-breaks. Java's `writeline` puts a different line-break than `\n`. If you post this as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows, Linux and OS X use different code for new line '\n', '\n\r', '\r'. Editors can use different code too. But open should recognize all types.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open